# Create a live wallpaper?

Tags: desktop-background

I've gotten live wallpapers to work, but I'd like to create one now. I thought I'd ask here before I started delving into someone's PPA code.

Are they OpenGL based? (I assume they are) 
Is there a live wallpaper PPA that supports plugin-like live wallpaper creations?